# Business not found in google PlaceId finder

Tags: google-places-api

The business location is Verified and set as a physical location with the address.  It can be found in the general Google map but not the Google PlaceID finder map.  The business is Efficient Cooling Concepts.  I have called Google 4 times this week and they do not know why it is not showing. We need the Place ID to set up Google Reviews on our site via https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-places-reviews/

It worked before before google changed something.